# How do B-theorists think about absences?

Tags: time

How do [B-theorists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-theory_of_time) think about absences like annihilation?

A B-theorist about time says that change is not real, often due to [McTaggert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._M._E._McTaggart)'s argument about the unreality of time.

Does a B-theorist have to say that annihilation is mind dependent, too?

Comment: In B theory becoming is not an objective feature of reality, so the opposite of it, the unbecoming, is not either. Instead of objects moving through time they think of their entire worldlines as "truly" existing. But this means that creation/annihilation do have objective sense, they correspond to worldlines that break off, just not to the "coming into"/"going out of" being.